# AWS Download Error 403 On First Attempt Only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm having trouble setting up automated downloads from an AWS bucket. On the first attempt, it returns a 403 forbidden error. When I try again, it works fine. If I wait a few minutes and do it again, the same thing happens. First time fails with 403 error, second time works as long as I try again within a few seconds. Has anyone else come across this? I've tried this on many files... it's not specific to one file in the bucket.

Here are the commands I am entering. (The X's are not in the live run... that's just to privatize my credentials)

```
C:\Users\jka> SET aws_access_key_id=AKIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXLNJ
C:\Users\jka> SET aws_secret_access_key=1JcXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXcOZR
C:\Users\jka> SET role_arn=arn:aws:iam::955XXXXXXX24:user/svc-comp-files-exchange
C:\Users\jka> aws s3 cp "s3://data-exchange-prod-svc-comp-files-exchange/RESI/FromCLIENT/Onboarding_Activation_1918596894_20230327.dat.pgp" "\\prod-1\prod_vol1\JOBS\CLIENT_AWS_S3\IT\Test\Onboarding_Activation_1918596894_20230327.dat.pgp"
```

Comment: Instead of running `aws s3 cp ...` try running `aws sts get-caller-identity`. That's a test endpoint that identifies the user whose credentials you are currently using. Run it repeatedly and see if it gives an error like the other command, or always works as expected, and whether the output results change after the first run. Verify that the local clock on the computer where you are running this is accurate, relative to whatever time zone is configured on the local computer (e.g. at noon US/Eastern, your computer clock should NOT say 12:00 if its time zone is actually set to US/Pacific).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I ran this at least 25 times it returned my identity info every time and never changed. No errors. The clock on the machine is fine too.

Comment: Take a look in Event History in Cloudtrail in account 955XXXXXXX24, (set Event name to `AssumeRole`) and see when the role is being assumed.  Is it after that initial request that failed, or is it before?  Take a look at the logs for the bucket.  Is the `Requester` the same for successful and failed requests?  Run AWS CLI with `--debug`.  Note the debug output line "Retrieved credentials will expire at" and see if this tells you anything.  Also find the line following the "Response body:" debug output to see if there is any info there that the normal error message isn't telling you about.